# For every simple graph like $G$ , $\chi(G) \le {(2e)}^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

$\chi(G)$: The chromatic number of a graph $G$ is the smallest number of colors needed to color the vertices of $G$ so that no two adjacent vertices share the same color.

Now the question:

Assume that $G$ is a simple graph. How can we prove that ${(2e)}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is an upper bound for $\chi(G)$?

Note: $e$ is the number of edges in $G$ and $v$ is the number of vertices.

What I know about the solution:

I know that if $G$ is a graph with degree sequence $(d_1,d_2,\dots,d_v)$ , then $\chi(G) \le \max_i \space \{\min\space\{d_i+1,i\}\}$, and I know this should lead to the proof that my question needs.  But I don't know the relationship between these two things.

Notice that this question is from the book "Graph Theory with Applications" written by Bondy & Murty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something is wrong here: when $G = K_n$, $\chi(G) = n$ but $(2e(G))^{1/2} = \bigl(2\binom{n}{2}\bigr)^{1/2} = (n(n-1))^{1/2} < n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure the identites you state are useful in this case.

Let $G$ be properly colored. Since there has to be at least one edge between any two colors clases, we have $$e \geq {\chi(G) \choose 2} = \chi(G)(\chi(G)+1)/2 \geq \chi(G)^2/2$$ and the result follows.

Comment: Careful: ${\chi(G) \choose 2} = \chi(G)(\chi(G)-1)/2 < \chi(G)^2/2$.